# Quality difference between source and timeline render

Tags: premiere, video-quality, cs6

I'm testing some high quality footage from Arri (https://www.arri.com/EN/camera/alexa/learn/alexa_sample_footage/) and I've noticed that PP when rendering the timeline lowers the quality considerably.

If you reference the below image, I have only added a title only and the timeline render quality in PP is awful.

Both my playback and pause resolution is full.

If I remove the title from the timeline the full quality is restored. This issue will occur with any PP effect. If I don't render the timeline, the program sequence runs at full quality.

The final render out is fine, but I want to work with the footage in high quality as my machine is more than capable. What am I missing here?

CPU: i7 4770K @ 4.3

MEM: 32GB

GPU: GTX970

SSD Disks

[image: Difference between source and program]

Answer (score 1):

after posting this I randomly stumbled upon a setting in Preferences.

Preferences -> Memory

Optimize rendering for performance
Changed to "Memory"

Looks fine now.

Comment: Please also mark this question as solved ;)

Comment: Note that the timeline render isn't necessarily the final result. How you set the export settings determines the quality of the final output.